# How to add .NET 7++ to Visual Studio 2022++ as target framework?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0, .net-8.0

I just installed the .NET to my machine. Yet, Visual Studio 2022 doesn't list the new SDK in its list of target frameworks:

[image: Obsolete target frameworks listed]

In Visual Studio Installer there is no ".NET 7 Target Framework" option to check.

How can I get Visual Studio 2022 to list the new SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Visual Studio to the latest version. As stated in the .NET 7 [release notes](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.md#visual-studio-compatibility):

> You need Visual Studio 17.4 or later to use .NET 7.0 on Windows.

Also be sure that correct workloads are installed.

For preview .NET versions I recommend to use preview VS versions too.